# How to fold a horizontal series into a vertical one

Tags: spreadsheet

I have a set of data that is contained in a `.csv` spreadsheet arranged like this:

```
name | 2006 | 2007 | 2008 | 2009
--------------------------------
foo  | 28   | 48   | 395  | 3829
bar  | 83   | 475  | 350  | 46
```

I need to rearrange this data so it looks like this:

```
name | date | value
-------------------
foo  | 2006 | 28
foo  | 2007 | 48
foo  | 2008 | 395
foo  | 2009 | 3829
bar  | 2006 | 83
bar  | 2007 | 475
bar  | 2008 | 350
bar  | 2009 | 46
```

I was thinking I could do this with a spreadsheet formula, something like `row.valueEntry = inputSheet[row.index/4 + 1][row.index % 4 + 1]`, but I have not yet figured out how to implement it in spreadsheet-formula-language.

Is there a better way to accomplish this sort of rearranging?

(BTW, I do not have access to MS Excel, as I am on Ubuntu, but answers that need things specific to excel might still be useful to other users.)

Comment: I think the thing for this in Excel is a "pivot table".  I'll think about a simple spreadsheet code...

Comment: It looks like LibreOffice also has a pivot table, but I don't know how good it is.

Comment: @anorton Well I just finished doing it by hand, 27,000 rows of it, with some fairly repetitive but fairly simple block copying. I would copy a column over to a second page, where I had the other data rows to the left, and a column to the right set up so all cells equaled the pasted column's header, then copied all the resulting rows to a third sheet using 'paste values only'.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the following [link](http://openoffice.blogs.com/openoffice/2006/11/data_pilots_in_.html) for steps how to pivot table in OpenOffice that is available for Linux.

The following [link](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/pivottable-reports-101-HA001034632.aspx) is for handling same result in MS Excel.